# How can I rectify this error -"Error fetching remote repo 'origin'" in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket

I am receiving error present in the below image, while trying to checkout code from the repository via Jenkins. Kindly guide on how to resolve this.I am new to Jenkins so I am not much aware of how it works.

[image: Error obtained from the stage logs(General SCM)]

This is the stage checkout code used in Jenkinsfile. Please guide on how to resolve the issue. 
[image]

Comment: Can you go through the solutions mentioned in this [post](https://github.com/jenkinsci/ghprb-plugin/issues/466) If in any case, it will not work, please comment back.

Comment: Thanks, the issue got resolved. Sorry for the late reply.